# Mac terminal error message: Xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found

Tags: macos, terminal, anaconda

I installed an environment file on Anaconda Navigator on my `Mac OSX 10.15.1`. Then every time I started a new terminal, the following message was repeated 7 times.

> xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.

It also had a pop-up window with the following error message:

> The "scrun" command requires the command line developer tools. Would you like to install the tools now?

So I installed the command line developer tools. But it experienced a long delay every time when I started a new terminal window. So I removed these tools. But the original error message shows up again.

How should I fix the problem?

Comment: For most compilation in Mac OS X you need Xcode and the command line tools, so removing those is not a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the command line developer tools that the xcrun pop-up window installed is an older version. I went to Apple developer's site to download the latest command line tools. The problem went away!